# find all next lines when previous line contains a string

Tags: c#, readline

I'm working on an ASP mvc application and i'm trying to get all the next lines when previous line contains a word

I've used the code below but i just can get the last line that contains the word given

```
int counter = 0;
string line;
List<string> found = new List<string>();
// Read the file and display it line by line.
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\Chaimaa\\Documents\\path.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    if (line.Contains("fact"))
    {
        found.Add(line);
    }
    foreach (var i in found)
    {
        var output = i;
        ViewBag.highlightedText = output;
    }
}
```

Any help on what should I add to 
1- get ALL lines that contains the word
2- and preferably get the ALL NEXT lines

Answer (score 1):

You can use an overload of `Where` that provides an index, store indexes in a hash set, and use the containment check to decide if a line should be kept or not, like this:

```
var seen = new HashSet<int>();
var res = data.Where((v, i) => {
    if (v.Contains("fact")) {
        seen.Add(i);
    }
    return seen.Contains(i-1);
});
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/cpz3nl)

As a side benefit, `seen` would contain indexes of all lines where the word `"fact"` has been found.

Comment: Thanks, but data rerfers to what ?

Comment: @ItShine `data` is an `IEnumerable<string>` obtained from file, for example by calling [`File.ReadLines`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `PairWise` method that takes in a sequence of values and returns a sequence containing each item paired with the item that came before it:

```
public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, T>> Pairwise<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        T prev = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            yield return Tuple.Create(prev, iterator.Current);
            prev = iterator.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

With this method we can pair off each of the lines, get the lines where the previous value contains a word, and then project out the second value, which is the line after it:

```
var query = lines.Pairwise()
    .Where(pair => pair.Item1.Contains(word))
    .Select(pair => pair.Item2);
```

Comment: Thank you but line is a string , what should I do to get it as IEnumerable ?

Comment: @ItShine Use `File.ReadLines` to get an `IEnumerable<string>` representing the lines in a file.